# Button alignment issue?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am using a table and a div to create a centered button group...but for some reason, my buttons are aligned weird? Here is a jsfiddle of the issue. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J7rYF/)

Is there any way I can fix this to where I can add more buttons and have them straight?
If more code is required, please ask me and I will post it.

Here is my html:

```
 <div align = "center" class="bdy">

        <table class="wrapper">

            <tr>

                <td>

                    <button type="button">Services</button>

                    <br>

                    <button type="button">Live</button>

                </td>


            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>​
```

My CSS is on the fiddle!

Comment: Just use tables for tabular data. Will have a look though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the alignment by removing the whitespace between buttons, but this is not the right way to do it.

Fixed version (reference only): http://jsfiddle.net/J7rYF/1/

Tables shouldn't be used to layout buttons. `div align=center` is deprecated. `<br>` shouldn't be used for this type of formatting purpose.

If you want an out of-the-box example/solution, [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons) has some very nice examples and templates.

Or, here's a simple template that you can start with for centering a list of buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/J7rYF/10/

### HTML

```
<div class="button-set">
    <ul>
        <li><button type="button">Services</button></li>
        <li><button type="button">Live</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.button-set {
   width: 300px;
   margin: 0 auto; /* this centers the element */       
}

.button-set UL {
    list-style: none; /* removes bullets */  
}

/* this controls spacing between adjacent buttons */
.button-set LI + LI {   
    margin-top: 4px;
}

/* width: 100% is needed...everything else is optional */
BUTTON {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #006DCC;
}
```

​

Comment: Ha, well, was using the center tags, then i was informed to use the align = "center"

Comment: Tim - Was about to post a similar solution. Elite - tables should not be used for this.

Comment: Hey, i get this list like bullets, and it is not centered...how do i fix it?

Comment: The bullets don't show in JS Fiddle because they use a reset stylesheet. If you don't use a reset, you'll need to remove the bullets manually. Example/fiddle updated.

Answer (score 2):

Getting rid of the `<br>` between the buttons fixed it for me.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but is there a way to add spacing between each button? How would i do that?

Comment: @EliteGamer - The other answers have more on the proper HTML to use here.  Tables aren't really suited for this; I'd lean toward a UL myself, but you could achieve that with lots of set-ups.  The CSS property you're interested in is margin-bottom.

Comment: @EliteGamer - No problem!  Check out Tim's answer - it looks like exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You give `margin:0;` at button css and `.button-set ul li{margin:0}`

Comment: You have been warned before. *Stop* including the link to your chat site.

Answer (score -1):

you can add another table inside that td and inside new table you can put these two buttons